# How can I display these text elements to the right of the images?

Tags: html, css

I want the following:

```
======
=img1=  Text
======

======
=img2=  Some more Text
======
```

Current HTML:

```
<div id="divison-id">
    <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img1.png"></a>
    <p>Text</p>
    <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img2.png"></a>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

When I add the following CSS rule:

```
#division-id p {
    display: in-line
}
```

I get this:

```
======      ======
=img1= Text =img2= Some more Text
======      ======
```

Why is this happening and what would be the correct way to solve this?

Comment: The most simpliest way would be to add <br> after first img text, but it's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the HTML a bit, try wrapping the `<p>` and `<img />` inside another `<div>` or something like this:

```css
#divison-id p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="divison-id">
  <div>
    <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img1.png"></a>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img2.png"></a>
    <p>Some more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And note, there are two errors:

1. There's no `display: in-line`.
2. The selector is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#division-id p:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Add <br> tag after each <p> tag. Like this:


<div id="divison-id">
 <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img1.png"</a>
 <p>Text goes right</p><br/>
 <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img2.png"</a>
 <p>Some more text</p><br/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#divison-id p{ display:inline; vertical-align:top}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I added `<div class='item'>` to wrap each image and text

```
<div id="division-id">
    <div class='item'>
        <a href="[href]">
            <img src="images/img1.png">
        </a>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <a href="[href]">
            <img src="images/img2.png">
        </a>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #division-id p {
        display: inline
    }
</style>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use lis instead of divs and brs, because you don't need to style anything extra.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="division-id">
  <li>
    <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img1.png"></a>
    <p>Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img2.png"></a>
    <p>Some more text</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this. I personally suggest that you do not use float:left cuz it will limit your styling in terms of height and width.

```
<style type="text/css">
.division_id div, .division_id>div>p{
    display:inline-block;
}
.division_id>div>a{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
<html>
<div class="division_id">
    <div>
        <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img1.png"></a>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="[href]"><img src="images/img2.png"></a>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```